# Why do I get "panicked at 'Couldn't find Windows home drive key" error when running sugar guard show?

Tags: candy-machine-v3, sugar

So I came back to my candy machine on devnet to adjust the guards and when I run:

*sugar guard show*

I get this error:

[1/1] Loading candy guard
thread 'main' panicked at 'Couldn't find Windows home drive key.', src\parse.rs:14:46
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

The command worked the other day but today this error. Is there something I must reset/configure when I come back to the candy machine? I have run *solana config set -u devnet* successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sugar` detects that you are on windows and is looking for the `HOMEDRIVE` env variable, which is not set, or maybe doesn't have access to.

It uses `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` env vars to get the path where the solana config file is. Something like `~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml`.

Make sure these env variables are set and available where you're running `sugar`.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes I had installed Solana as administrator, but was logged in as a different user when running the sugar commands, and it was looking in the wrong place for config.yml. Appreciate you pointing me to the solution!